# Usando ajax serialize no Laravel

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, laravel

## O que preciso

Quando o usuário clicar no botão de enviar o ajax chamará um método de uma classe para verificar se o texto digitado já existe e em uma tabela. Ela retorna o resultado, caso seja falso ela deixa o form ser enviado e o campo é cadastrado no bd, caso contrário ele apresentará um alert com o texto digitado e que ele já existe.

## O que eu fiz

Criei o form usando o blade e fiz o `type="button"` em html puro por não achar na documentação do Laravel.

### home.blade.php

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'HomeController@gerarPdf','method' => 'POST')) !!}
    {!! Form::text('numeroDocumento[]', null,array(
        'placeholder' => 'Código da Entidade',
        'maxlength' => '5',
        'required' => ''
    )); !!}
    <input type="button" value="Gerar Código" name="submitBarcode" id="submitBarcode" required/>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

### routes.php

```
Route::post('verificarBarcode', 'HomeController@verificarBarcode');
```

### js

```
$('#submitBarcode').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url : 'verificarBarcode',
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $('#formBarcodeId').serialize(),
            success : function(msg){
                if (msg.status == 0) {
                    alert("Tem Coisa Repetida");
                }
                else{
                    alert("Não Tem Coisa Repetida");
                }
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });,
```

Quando clico no enviar ele dá esse alert com todo o código html do resultado. Eu copiei o código pra uma página vazia e ele me resultou nessa imagem. Pq ele está dando esse problema com o token ?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: De onde vem o `#formBarcodeId` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não sei se só 'verificarBarcode' funciona no seu 'url' dentro do ajax.

Tente usar:

```
url: "{{ URL::to('verificarBarcode') }}";
```

---

Pelo que percebi o problema é o ajax achar a função no laravel.

Eu fiz um código em ajax simples com laravel e funcionou, tente fazer isso, caso não funcione eu diria que é alguma configuração básica pendente do laravel, mas tente o código abaixo para testar a conexão:

Javascript

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url : 'verificarBarcode',
        cache: false,
        data: { name: 'rodrigo' }
    }).done(function(msg){
        alert(msg)
    });
});
```

Rota:

```
Route::post('verificarBarcode', 'HomeController@verificarBarcode');
```

Função no Controller:

```
function verificarBarcode(){
    return 'olá mundo';
}
```

Comment: Assim eu recebo "You don't have permission to access /barcode/public/{{ URL::to('verificarBarcode') }} on this server."

Comment: Tente colocar Route::any ao invés de ::post

Comment: Certinho, fera. Eu estava esquecendo de colocar no form o id formBarcodeId.